# Passing data to a bootstrap modal from Laravel

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, laravel

Wonder if someone can help me with this one.  I am a complete newbie with JS and JQuery.

I want to avoid accidents with deleting posts in my blog, so I want to have it so that when I hit delete it will pop up a modal to confirm I do want to delete the post and then do it or not.

I have added the following code.

```
 <!-- Button trigger modal to delete post -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-xs" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#deletePost">
  Delete
</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="deletePost" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Delete Blog Post</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>You are about to delete a blog post, are you sure all that effort is to be sent to the unrecoverable trash can?</p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default pull-left" data-dismiss="modal">OMG, NO!!!</button>
        <form action="/blog/{{ $post->id }}" method="POST">
            {{ csrf_field() }}
            {{ method_field('DELETE') }}
            <button type="submit" class="pull-right btn btn-danger">Delete it!</button>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Now all that works fine, all I now want to do is that when I click the "delete it!" button it will do just that.

It all works apart from deleting the right post, I want to pass

```
{{ $post->id }}
```

to the modal so that it will send the post id to the controller.

My question is how I pass the id above to the modal?  I have read a lot of examples and they are all so different so thought it better to get some views.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you using RESTful controller? Please, include it in the question.

Comment: Yes I am using a RESTful controller.  Will do.

Answer (score 1):

I would very much recommend using [SweetAlert](http://t4t5.github.io/sweetalert/) plugin, it is visually compatible with Twitter Bootstrap and much more pleasant to use.
This is a piece of code for **multilingual**, **model-independant** delete function:

```
    $('body').on('click', 'sweet-delete', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var id = $(this).data('id');
        var model = $(this).data('model');
        swal({
            title: lang.confirm_please,
            text: lang.delete_warning,
            type: "warning",
            showCancelButton: true,
            confirmButtonColor: "#DD6B55",
            confirmButtonText: lang.delete_button,
            closeOnConfirm: false,
            showLoaderOnConfirm: true,

        }, function(){
            $.post('/'+model+'/'+id, {_method: 'DELETE'}, function(data){
                swal({
                    title: lang.delete_title,
                    text: lang.delete_success,
                    type: "success",
                    timer: 5000
                }, function(){
                    window.location.href = '/'+model;
                });
            });
        });
    })
```

And in you view:

```
<button data-id="{{$post->id}}" data-model="blog" class="pull-right btn btn-danger sweet-delete">@lang('app.delete')</button>
```

I have to mention that in order to attach CSRF token to my ajax forms I use:

```
$.ajaxSetup({
        headers: {'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')}
    });
```

in my app.js, and

```
<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{csrf_token()}}">
```

in my main layout file.

Answer (score 1):

To pass the `post ID` to the modal form, it should be inserted in the modal using jQuery.

Button:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-xs delete-post" data-post-id="{{ $post->id }}">Delete</button>
```

Note: we will trigger the modal using the following, so we can also insert the ID.

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var modalObj = $('#deletePost');

  $('.delete-post').click(function(e) {
    var postId = $(this).data('post-id');

    modalObj.find('form').attr('action', '/blog/' + postId);
    modalObj.modal('show');
  });
});
```

In this case, the `action` attribute is set dynamically, according to the relevant post id.

Comment: Didn't you see `{{ method_field('DELETE') }}` in the question?

Comment: What are you talking about?  `DELETE /photos/{photo} destroy photos.destroy` (source: https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/controllers#resource-controllers)

Comment: Again, why would you need to load stuff to the modal with js, if the modal is preloaded with needed values with the page. I am pretty sure, this is a part of a view, specific to a current post and not a list of posts.

Comment: Thats not the point, read the question subject please. What I am suggesting, is just a simple way to 'pass data to a bootstrap modal'.

Comment: What is the point then? Poster asked how he could pass the data to the modal, and he is doing that by loading the data to the modal with the page. You are reloading action attribute with the same value onclick and telling me this is what he wanted? I would understand this usage, if you would want to get rid of that form in the modal, or the modal itself, like in my answer.